# With argparse is it possible to make previously defined arguments required?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm currently defining a set of command line arguments for a couple of related scripts which I want them to use the same arguments for a given context without having to copy/paste the according sections.

In some contexts a given argument is optional in others it's required so I can't just set up one common argument parser and use it among all scripts.

One way would be to have a function `create_argument_parser(flags)` which creates a parser based on given flags.

Another way would be to define an argument parser first and modify it according to my needs.

Is there a way to define a set of arguments first and make them optional/required afterwards?

Comment: You can find the "greatest common parser" and put that in your generic function and then add necessary arguments for each script. But from what you say it sounds like they are not so common, why not just define for each script its own argparser? It's much more readable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import argparse
```

`argparse` is written with Python's class structure, so most commands produce objects which can be examined, and to a limited degree modified.  But do so intelligently.  Don't be afraid to write your own utility functions, and even classes if that helps.

First we make a `parser` object:

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: parser
Out[3]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipython3', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

`add_argument` creates an `Action` object, and puts it on the `parser._actions` list.  It also returns it, and we can retain that reference.

```
In [4]: a1 = parser.add_argument('foo')
In [5]: a1
Out[5]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [6]: a1.required
Out[6]: True
In [7]: a2 = parser.add_argument('--bar')
In [8]: a2
Out[8]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [9]: a2.required
Out[9]: False
In [10]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--bar BAR] foo

positional arguments:
  foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --bar BAR
```

`positionals` are, by default `required`.  `optionals` are not, though we can specify that parameter, creating a 'required optional'.

But since `required` is a simple attribute of the `Action` we can change it:

```
In [11]: a2.required=True
In [12]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython3 [-h] --bar BAR foo
```

So whether you use utility scripts to create the parsers, or make modifications like this, is up to you.  This modification route might be harder to maintain/debug.  Be extra careful about making attribute changes when using the `parents` mechanism to create multiple (sub)parsers.